# Dear all flutter developer I would like to ask about How to draw line as the image below "flutter concept"?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sGfX.jpg)

Dear all flutter developer I would like to ask about How to draw line as the image below "flutter concept"? I meaning vertical line sharp.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you to use the `CustomPaint` class, with this you are able to paint custom shapes.

- Docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html
- Official video-guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvI_NUXK00s